# Backbone.js: Dynamic model/collection url based on user input

Tags: backbone.js

I'm total new to Backbone so please pointing me the right way to do it. Here is what I have:

1. A Backbone login View with 3 inputs: serverIP, username, password. I am doing all the validation and send jquery ajax() request to my backend host based on the serverIP that the user has to enter earlier.
2. My backend is js PHP using Slim restful framework, check user, password like usual basic stuff.
3. On the callback of successful ajax() call, I want to set the urlRoot for latter use of all models and collections as I'm using Slim for all database interactions and this PHP file located on the server.

I tried to set it on the global app variable like this in app.js:

```
var app = {
api_url: '',
views: {},
models: {},
routers: {},
utils: {},
adapters: {}
```

};

In the callback of login view I set:

```
app.api_url = "http://"+serverIP;
```

And try to use app.api_url in backbone model url but it's apparently undefined.

May be this is not the correct approach I'm trying and I messed up with the variable scope? Then how can I set model.url from the view? Please, any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Hungnd

**EDIT:** Ok, I will try to elaborate my problem again:

1. Here is the login function in my **LoginView.js**, basically it take user inputs and send to my model to interact with the server, if success navigate to home view:

   ```
   var user = new app.models.Login();

   var userDetails = {
       serverIP: $('#serverIP').val(),
       username: $('#username').val(),
       password: $('#password').val()
   };

   user.save(userDetails, {
       success: function(data) {
           /* update the view now */
           if(data.error) {  // If there is an error, show the error messages

           }   
           else { // If not, send them back to the home page

                   app.router = new app.routers.AppRouter();
                   app.router.navigate('home',true);

           }
       },
       error: function() {
           /* handle the error code here */

       }
   ```
2. Here is my **LoginModel.js**, get the serverIP from user input on login form and send to the server to process

   ```
   app.models.Login = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: function(){ 
   var serverIP = this.get('serverIP');

   return "http://"+serverIP+"/api/login";         
   },

   defaults: {
       'serverIP': '',
   'username': '',
   'password': '',
   }

   });
   ```
3. Now, after successful login, navigate to **HomeView.js**, on initialize it calls to EmployeeCollection, so far so good

   ```
   initialize: function () {

   //Search result
   this.searchResults = new app.models.EmployeeCollection();
   this.searchResults.fetch({data: {name: ''}});
   this.searchresultsView = new app.views.EmployeeListView({model: this.searchResults});

   }
   ```
4. Here is my **EmployeeModel.js** where I have the problem, I dont know how to access the serverIP variable.

   ```
   app.models.Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({

   urlRoot:"api/employees",
   //urlRoot: app.api_url+"/api/employees",

      initialize:function () {
          this.reports = new app.models.EmployeeCollection();
          this.reports.url = app.api_url+'/api/employees/' + this.id + '/reports';
      }

      });

   app.models.EmployeeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

   model: app.models.Employee,

   //url: "api/employees",
   url: function() {
       //How to get serverIP?

   },


   });
   ```

Comment: you did not give any relevant code. Try with a static url root then refactor your code so the url root is made dynamic. you can use a model to hold user credentials and the server url.

Comment: I edited my question with relevant code. Please check again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All models in backbone already have an url property which will be used to fetch data. In your case you could define it as a function to generate url dynamically.

Here is an example :

```
//we are inside the definition of the loginModel

data: {
      serverIP : null,
       username : null,
       password : null
          },

url: function() {
        var url = "rootUrl",
        data = this.get("data");
    return function() {
        return url + '?' + $.param(data);
       };
    }
```

url is then defined as a closure, and object being references in javascript, the url generated will use the current values in the data object.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I take your way of doing loginModel in backbone but still I dont know how to access serverIP from the model/collection. Please check my edit above. Thanks!